# POM Model Data and Locator Locations

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor

When testing using the POM model data pattern, is it best to have the locators for elements in the page object or have them in a separate file like the test data

```
pageObject
    loginPage
    homePage

testDate 
    loginPageData
    homePageData

pageLocators
    loginPageLocators
    homePageLocators
specs
    loginTest.js
```

Many thanks

Comment: Page object is place for locators

Answer (score 0):

Everything is good what is good FOR YOU. There is no single right answer. So I'll share my experience utilizing POM in my current project.

No one ever thought of one minor downside of POM: navigation down the chain to get to the bottom locators.

I worked for a while with perfectionists who believed if something is logically different, it should go into a separate file. Thus, we had locators stored separately from elementFinders and methods that interact with pages. This was reasonable, but consider what I need to go through if I debug a failed test:

- to find a failed line in a spec and jump in the source code of the method that causes error
- This method belongs to extended class and depends on parental class, so I jump in the source of the class
- That method interacts with an element, defined somewhere else, so I have to open that file
- the element has locator stored in another file, so I need to find that file too

Finally, when I found my locator, I forgot what I was doing, not to mention tediousness of the process and waste of time.

Therefore in my next project, I tried to balance this neatness of the code with overall usability and easiness of navigation between files, and was happy with the way I structured the code

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your incite. I was worried about trying to split thing up to much.